# I want to check if the pdf document contains cross reference stream or table in web application c#. How to check?

Tags: pdf, cross-reference

I have an c# web application and I want to check if the pdf document contains cross reference stream. And if it contains the cross reference stream then convert it to reference table.

Answer (score 1):

Detection is fairly easy. Search the file from its end for "%%EOF"; proper PDF files actually end with an '%%EOF' line, not so proper ones may have some trash bytes following that marker. The line before that marker line contains the position of the last cross references (cf. [Adobe copy of ISO-32000-1:2008](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf) section 7.5.5). Go to the position noted here.

If at that position you find the xref keyword, the PDF has a cross reference table. If you find a PDF stream object instead (ibidem section 7.5.8), the PDF has a cross reference stream. If you find neither there, something about the file is fishy.

Conversion is difficult, though, especially if the PDF also uses object streams which only can be used with cross reference streams. You might want to use a library like iText(Sharp) to read the PDF and export it again with less compression enabled.

Furthermore, if the PDF is signed, conversion is impossible without breaking the signature.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of a hack, but you can use following code to detect if a PDF contains cross-reference streams.

The code uses [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/).

```
public static bool ContainsCrossReferenceStreams(string fileName)
{
    using (PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument(fileName))
    {
        return document.SaveOptions.UseObjectStreams;
    }
}
```

When the library opens a PDF it sets `SaveOptions.UseObjectStreams` to `true` if the source document uses cross-reference streams. Otherwise the property returns `false`.

Disclaimer: I work for the vendor of the library.

Answer (score 0):

one thing to note when converting from a cross-reference stream to something you can parse is that a cross-reference stream allows for a new type of reference entries. Along **"uncompressed"**, and **"free"** you now have **"compressed"** as a new reference type.

This entry cannot directly be converted 1:1 to a normal cross-reference table. A **"compressed"** reference entry inside of a cross-reference stream points to a so called **"object stream"**. The latter contains multiple indexed objects. A "compressed" entry in the xref stream then names an object stream and an index. The first line inside an object stream is then used to resolve the index to a byte-offset inside the object stream.

If that topic is still of interest to you I suggest that you have a look at chapter **"3.4.7 Cross-Reference Streams"**. Especially the paragraph **"Compatibility with Applications That Do Not Support PDF 1.5"** can help. It deals with a so called **"hybrid-reference"** that does what you want somehow.

Now, that we more or less know how to convert an xref stream to an xref table let's continue with detecting an xref stream.

- You can search for a stream with **/Type/XRef** (with variable spaces between the two keywords).
- Also, if you have any streams of **/Type/ObjStm** you can deduce that there must be a xref stream, since only xref streams can point to object streams ;) (see above for an explanation).
- Last but not least, if the **PDF version** of the document that you parse is **less than 1.5** you can be somewhat sure that no xref stream is included. This heavily depends on the PDF authoring tool that created your document. Some stick to the reference some don't.

I hope this helps.